Padding as a percentage of child height (unknown height)
I am trying to add padding to a child element in Flutter, but I want the padding to be a percentage of the child's height. The problem is that the child's height is unknown at the time of building the widget.
For example, if the child's height is 500px, I want to add 20% padding (100px) to the top and bottom. I have tried using the EdgeInsets.symmetric constructor, but it only allows me to set a fixed padding value in pixels.
Is there a way to achieve this in Flutter, even if the child's height is unknown?
Here is an example of my code:
Padding(
  child: Image.network(getRandomImage()),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50), // This should be 20% of child height
),

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

you have to calculate the height if the childreen, then rebuild the parent with current padding value

Use LayoutBuilder to measure child‘s height, here is an example
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double height = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: height * 0.2),
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          setState(() {
            height = constraint.maxHeight;
          });
        });

        return Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 500,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}


this doesn't work in ListView.. Help?

Try this simpler way :
Padding(
    child: Image.network(getRandomImage()),
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2),
),

